# Why cannot I use String.Contains() if default string is null?

Tags: c#, .net, string

From [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public bool Contains(
    string value
)
```

Return Value: **true** if the value parameter occurs within this string, or if *value* is the empty string (""); otherwise, **false**.

Exception: [ArgumentNullException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception(v=vs.110).aspx): *value* is **null**.

Example:

```
string s = string.Empty; //or string s = "";
Console.WriteLine(s.Contains("Hello World!")); //output: False
```

If I change it to:

```
try
{
   string s = null; //or string s;
   Console.WriteLine(s.Contains("Hello World!"));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

It'll throw an error message: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` since `string` doesn't have a default value (like `""`) from [Default Values Table (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx),

Please come back to the example, the code will work if I declare `s`:

```
string s = "";
```

Now, *Object `s` is set to an instance of an object*.

So, my question is: Does MSDN forgot something like: `s` cannot be **null**?

To check it, I've tried:

```
string s = null;
Console.WriteLine(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? s.Contains("Hello World!") : false);
```

It should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: method calls aren't allowed on `null`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You changed the **value** with the **instance**.

```
myString.Contains(anotherString)
```

Here `myString` is the **instance** on which you call the method `Contains`, whereas `anotherString` is the **value** passed to the method. If this value is `null` the method will throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

When changing the **instance** to `null` on the other hand it surely leads to NRE as you can´t call any member on a null-reference. However if you set it to `string.empty` `Contains` will return `false` because the empty string does not contain *anything* (in particular `string.empty` does not contain `"Hello World"`, however `"Hello world"` contains the empty string).

So the following returns `false`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Empty.Contains("Hello World"));
```

Whilst this returns `true`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World".Contains(string.Empty));
```

Anyway what you want to check is if the empty string IS contained in any other one:

```
var retVal = myString.Contains(string.empty);
```

Which should return `true`.

Furthermore `myString.Contains(null)` leads to `ArgumentNullException`

On the other side `null.Contains(aString)` leads to the NRE.

Answer (score 7):

the new compilier allows you to do it with the condition check simplified.

```
string s = null;
Console.WriteLine(s?.Contains("Hello World!"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this question is more about the difference between *value* types (which cannot be null) and *reference* types (which can be). In C# and other OO languages it's to do with memory handling.

The value types listed in your MSDN article are all of a known size - e.g. `int` will *always* be 32 bits in size etc. Under the hood, these are all `structs`. As they are of fixed size regardless of the value, C# stores them on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). As `null` by definition doesn't refer to anything, it has no size. It doesn't make sense for something that exists with a fixed size to also exist with no size.

If you read the documentation for `string` on MSDN a little closer, you'll see the `string` is a *class* not a struct. This is because a string can be of any length you like, so it has to be stored as a pointer to some data on the [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#Dynamic_memory_allocation). When you declare a reference type variable, it creates a pointer on the stack to a location on the heap, but there won't be anything at that address until you give that variable a value. **Until then, the pointer for that variable is pointing and memory containing literally nothing - i.e. `null`** and it doesn't make sense to try to find "Hello World!" in nothing. An empty string is still a string, but `null` is literally nothing.

This is probably more detail than you were expecting, but it's good to have an appreciation of the underlying principles of a language, even if you don't need them day to day. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76153/Six-important-NET-concepts-Stack-heap-value-types) is well worth a read if you want to go a little more in depth. The idea of `null` can be a weird concept to get your head around, but once you get the hang of it, it all makes sense, honest!

Comment: Oh. Sorry. But I haven't read any document yet which says *the `string` is a class not a struct*. I agree with you that `string` is a reference type which is stored in Heap. But if `string` is a `class`, I can declare property for a `string`, can't I? Maybe I don't understand you mean.

Comment: It doesn't explicitly say it, but if you look at the syntax for [string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) and [int](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx), one is a `class` and one is a `struct`. As for properties, the `string` class has two properties, `Length` and `Chars`, however they're defined so that you can only get their values, not set them - that wouldn't make sense!

Comment: `string` and `class` are 2 objects. It's not for `struct` and `int`. `struct` and `int` are value types, not reference types. You cannot compare them.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ensure that your output is bool (not bool? nullable bool) to be able to use it in conditionals.  You'll want to use the simplified condition check and the non-coalescing operator.  I ran into this using a linq query where it wouldn't let me use the bool? in place of a bool.  Instead use code like this:

```
List<string?> SL = new string?[] { null, "not null", "not null either", null, "null... just kidding" }.ToList();
string? result = SL.FirstOrDefault(s => s?.Contains("just") ?? false);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Because the strings in my list were nullable, the s in my linq query is also nullable.  So the Contains method returns a nullable bool, and the linq query needs to know how to handle a null result.  So using the ?? operator I told it to return false if the Contains method returns null.

Or another elegant way is to use the ?? operator on your string before running the Contains method.

```
string s = null;
Console.WriteLine((s ?? "").Contains("Hello World!"));
```